# Does TensorFlow Lite Have a Low Power Consumption Mode?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I saw that TF Lite has a [delegate](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/nnapi) that uses NNAPI for hardware acceleration.  I was reading up on [NNAPI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/neuralnetworks) and I saw that it has a [compilation setting](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/neural-networks#group___neural_networks_1gga034380829226e2d980b2a7e63c992f18a370c42db64448662ad79116556bcec01) called `ANEURALNETWORKS_PREFER_LOW_POWER`, which compiles a given NNAPI model to prioritize low power consumption.  Does TF Lite have a setting that utilizes this, or any, power-saving mode?  I'm developing for mobile using TF Lite for Android on Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the low-power option on the NNAPI delegate by setting [this option](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/delegates/nnapi/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/nnapi/NnApiDelegate.java#L42) while creating the delegate as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/nnapi).

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was looking over TF Lite's documentation and couldn't find anything about changing NNAPI options - your link is exactly what I was looking for!  I didn't realize there was a java file in TF Lite's Github for it.  I had read in the documentation a while back that the GPU Delegate's code was only provided in the binary and assumed that meant everything for all delegates.

Comment: No problem :-). Please 'accept' the answer if things look good. Thanks!